# Amazon Web Services - EC2: How do I stop my WordPress site showing the ip address as the domain?

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns

I am close to tearing my hair out on this issue as I just cannot seem to get my Wordpress site to not read the Amaazon Public IP address.

I have a domain name in GoDaddy and have changed a host record so that my domain name "http://example.com" redirects to "http://0.0.0.0".

However once this page loads, the url quickly changes back to the Public IP address.

I have tried changing the Site URL in the Wordpress Settings but this just breaks the site and does not allow me to log in.

What is it I am doing wrong? I just cant figure it out. I just want the domain name from goDaddy to appear as the URL.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First of all attach the Elastic IP to your EC2 Instance so it wont change public IP after you shutdown and restart your machine. Make A Record in your Godaddy DNS Record File that points to the elastic IP.

You have not changed the base URL of your wordpress thats why it is still redirecting to the old Base URL. Connect to your EC2 instance and edit wp-config.php add the following line of code

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I have attached the elastic ip to this instance and have tried changing the wordpress config to match what you said. Doing so stopped me being able to login. I dont know if it was a bug. But I typed my username and password and the login button did nothing. no validation either.

Comment: have you installed wp in a sub-directory?

Comment: No. I installed it in the root. And I can reach the wp-login page through the domain name I want, but the actual page still loads the IP